# Дан массив действительных чисел из N членов подсчитать сколько в нем отрицательных, положительных и нулевых элементов

Tags: python

Дан массив действительных чисел из N членов подсчитать сколько в нем отрицательных, положительных и нулевых элементов

Comment: И что у Вас не получилось?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5]

positive = 0
negative = 0
zero = 0

for num in my_list:
    if num > 0:
        positive += 1
        continue
    if num < 0:
        negative += 1
        continue
    zero += 1

print('Положительных: ', positive)
print('Отрицательных: ', negative)
print('Нулей: ', zero)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
massive = [1,2,3,4,5,0,5,4,0,-5,3,2,-1] #вместо massive подставляете свой массив 

pos = []
neg = []
zero = []

for num in massive:
    if num > 0:
        pos.append(num)
    elif num == 0:
        zero.append(num)
    else:
        neg.append(num)

print("Количество положительных: {}".format(len(pos)))
print("Количество отрицательных: {}".format(len(neg)))
print("Количество нулей: {}".format(len(zero)))
```

Comment: Не надо делать три дополнительных списка. Достаточно трех переменных с числом.

Comment: Не надо было отвечать на вопрос вообще.

Comment: @Эникейщик Если важно только количество, то да. Если нужны будут и сами значения - то нет.

Comment: И о чем же говорится в задаче?.. 

Comment: Сегодня не все могут в завтрашний день смотреть,
Вернее смотреть могут-то все, а видят не все :)